# pm2 start server.js command repeats itself how can I fix it

Tags: mysql, node.js, render, pm2, openai-api

I deploy my codes to a place called render, normally it works when I give the node server.js command, but when I say pm2 start server.js, the application runs the pm2 start server.js command over and over again, and I can't share it here because my codes are very comprehensive.

I tried some things, it didn't help like asking from chat gpt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.